# Wrong variable substitution that I am doing

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I spent 3 hours today on the following integral, (I am trying to verify why my variable substitution fails):

$$\int\int\frac{x^2\sin(xy)}{y}dxdy$$ over
$$\Omega=\{x^2<y<2x^2, y^2<x<2y^2\}$$ which is (everything is positive):
$$\Omega=\{1<y/x^2<2, 1<x/y^2<2\}$$

So, I deduced that for a proper transform $T$ we will get that:
$$T\Omega=\{(u,v)=T(x,y):1<u<2, 1<v<2\}$$
So we want the opposite of $T(x,y)=(y/x^2,x/y^2)$.

I will skip some of the calculations, but I got that:
$$|J_T|=3x^-2y^-2\Longrightarrow |J_{T^-1}|=3^{-1}x^2y^2$$
and that
$$T^{-1}(x,y)=(y^{-\frac{1}{3}}x^{-\frac{2}{3}},y^{-\frac{2}{3}}x^{-\frac{1}{3}})$$

and that

$$\int_\Omega f=\int_{T\Omega}f\circ T^{-1}|J_{T^{-1}}|$$

which is after putting all of the information:

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_1^2\int_1^2xy^2\sin(y^{-1}x^{-1})$$

And this is not leading to anywhere, and I also compared to a full solution that does somewhat similar variable substitution, and after that, he got similar, but solveable integral: $$\frac{1}{3}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1u\sin(uv)$$

I will appreciate any kind of help, I spent too much time on this

Comment: If you are substituting $u=\frac y{x^2}$ and $v=\frac x{y^2}$, then the Jacobian determinant should be $|J|=\frac1{3u^2v^2}$

Comment: For some reason, in this integral its confuses me to say what u,v are (because I used the transform to manipulate $\Omega$ to be a "better" set) So, as I see it I just used the substitute that comes from the opposite of $T(x,y)=y/x^2,x/y^2$

Comment: And if I am right, then I should take the inverse of the Jacobian of that T. (@user170231)

Comment: So if you can, please elaborate for me the reason of what you said

Comment: Your approach is fine, and you have the correct result for $J_{T^{-1}}$, you just left it in terms of $x$ and $y$. Under the substitution, $\frac{x^2y^2}3=\frac1{3u^2v^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=\frac x{y^2},v=\frac y{x^2} \implies x=\frac1{u^{\frac23}v^{\frac13}},y=\frac1{u^{\frac13}v^{\frac23}}$$

Hence

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}x_u&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac2{3u^{\frac53}v^{\frac13}}&-\frac1{3u^{\frac23}v^{\frac43}}\\-\frac1{3u^{\frac43}v^{\frac23}}&-\frac2{3u^{\frac13}v^{\frac53}}\end{bmatrix} \implies |\det J| = \frac1{3u^2v^2}$$

Then the integral becomes

$$\iint_\Omega\frac{x^2\sin(xy)}y\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \frac13\int_1^2\int_1^2 \frac1{u^2v^3} \sin\left(\frac1{uv}\right)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

Comment: Ok, first of all thank you. I think I am getting that, but there is one matter, as I said in the comments above, dont I do the *opposite* substitute of $u=x/y^2,v=y/x^2$?

Comment: and it is also make me more troubles, because from the integral you stated i am trying to substitute again to make the variables exponents to be positive, and the same issue goes, for writing the Jacobian 'in terms of u&v', I cant see where this issue comes from, and I checked the details in the proof of that theorem again.. @user170231